# How to add childNode to parentNode in ext.net?

Tags: c#, .net, load, ext.net, treepanel

I am new to ext.net and c# programming. I have a department table which has records with department-child department relaton in an Oracle DB. I got the records by using "connect by prior". I am planning to load tree foreach loop like following;

```
foreach (var obj in l)
{
    if (obj.DepartmentParentOid == null || obj.DepartmentParentOid == 0)
    {
        Ext.Net.Node root = new Ext.Net.Node();
        root.NodeID = obj.Oid.ToString();
        root.Text = obj.DepartmentName;
        root.Expanded = true;
        TreePanel1.Root.Add(root);
    }
    else
    {
        Ext.Net.NodeProxy np =  TreePanel1.GetStore().GetNodeById(obj.DepartmentParentOid);

        Ext.Net.Node child  = new Node();
        child.NodeID = obj.Oid.ToString();
        child.Text = obj.DepartmentName;
        np.AppendChild(child);
    }
}
```

But it gave me the exception:

> NullreferenceExeption was unhandled by user code"

I couldn't find what has caused this though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @IanKemp I checked, my store was null.I don't see why it is null.Is my approach above wrong ?

Comment: it is not an issue about ext.net but getting data

Comment: Related [Ext.NET forum thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?60271).

Comment: Thanks Daniil,It heps me.